# How can I update the sub document field from the sub document array based on the query?

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("552cd780e4b042752e540df5"),
"source": [
    {
        "bookid": ObjectId("552cd77e31456e192df6ad8e"),
        "isActive": false
    },
    {
        "bookid": ObjectId("552cd77e31456e192df6ad8a"),
        "isActive": true
    }
]
}
```

I need to update the above document , where the condition is the `source.bookid` is `ObjectId("552cd77e31456e192df6ad8e")` and update that particular document  field `isActive` as `false`. So, the resulting output I need as

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("552cd780e4b042752e540df5"),
"source": [
    {
        "bookid": ObjectId("552cd77e31456e192df6ad8e"),
        "isActive": false
    },
    {
        "bookid": ObjectId("552cd77e31456e192df6ad8e"),
        "isActive": true
    }
]
}
```

Can anyone please tell me , how to execute this update query? and also is it possible to retrieve all documents where the sub docments array contains all "isActive" as false?

Comment: In your sample document, how come the `source.bookid` is the same in the `source` array? Did you mean to have distinct book ids?

Comment: No the book id is not distinct, it will differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mongo update documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) for nesting key update use `$elemMatch` query as below

```
db.collectionName.update({"source":{"$elemMatch":{"bookid":ObjectId("552cd77e31456e192df6ad8e")}}},{"$set":{"source.$.isActive":false}})
```

If multiple document update then used this [mongo update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) add multi true.